# Ajax post is slow

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I have a page with from, and I maked an input, and when the user is writing, it's automaticlly will show the result from the DB(LIKE SEARCH).
I used jquery.
It's working but it's runing very slow.
Can antbody help me?

The code is:

```
<html>  
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='new_style.css' />
          <script src="jquery.js"></script>

          <script type='text/javascript'>
              setInterval(function() { 
                  $('.input').keyup(function(){
                      var a = $('.input').val();
                      $.post('select.php?id=28',{"name":a}, function(data){
                          $('#msg').html(data);
                      });
                  });
              },1000);
         </script>
    </head>
    <body>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    if(isset($_POST['name'])){
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        if($_POST['name']==""){
            echo "text";
        } else {
            $query = mysqli_query($user->getDB(),"SELECT * FROM bla WHERE name  LIKE '%$name%'");
            if(mysqli_num_rows($query)==0){
                echo "text";
            } else { ?>
        <table id='tables'>
            <tr>
                <th>name</th>
                <th>text</th>
                <th>text</th>
                <th>text</th>
            </tr><?php
                while($show =mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
                    echo $show['name'];
                }
            }
            echo "</table>";
            if(isset($_POST['check'])) {
                foreach($_POST['ch'] as $selected) {
                    echo $selected . " <br />";
                }
            }
        }
    } else { ?>
        <p id='msg'></p>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure the request is going slow? It's more likely that your query is slow. Try running the query directly against the database and see how long it takes. If it takes a while I would suggest adding an index on the `name` column.

Comment: Step 1 will be to identify the actual bottleneck.  You're issuing an AJAX request with *every keystroke*.  Is that really necessary?  Does that database query perform that fast?  How much data is coming back over HTTP?  It looks like you're responding with the entire page every time instead of just the new set of data.

Comment: Lovely [sql injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerability. Enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Comment: How many records in your `bla`table ? Is `name` field indexed ?

Answer (score 1):

for performance, try this

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function(){
        var pendingRequest;
        $('.input').keyup(function(){
            if(pendingRequest){
                pendingRequest.abort()
                pendingRequest = null;
            }

            var a = $('.input').val();
            pendingRequest = $.post('select.php?id=28',{"name":a}, function(data){
                pendingRequest = null;
                $('#msg').html(data);
            });
        });
    })
</script>
```

then fix the vulnerability, MarcB mentionied in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can add clearInterval() function. This will stop unnecessary requests.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('.input').keyup(function(){

     vidi = setInterval(function() { 

       clearInterval(vidi);
       var a = $('.input').val();
       $.post('select.php?id=28',{"name":a}, function(data){
          $('#msg').html(data);
       });
     },1000);

   });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're adding another callback every second. After 100 seconds, this will generate 100 requests per keystroke.

Remove setInterval and this will vastly improve.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by make a new php file and put in the mysqli codes with the while.
Thanks !